# nHibernate Future<T>, confusion about loading order

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I may be using the `Future<T>` method outright wrong, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to optimize its use. So here is my simple example.

Three objects, `Member`, `Player`, `Character`

```
Member {
   Player Player { get; set; }

Player {
   IList<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, one member is also one player, and one player has many characters. Simple enough. (the reason for this abstraction is to keep `Member` lightweight, so that it can be used only for authentication and roles, where more heavy data has to attach to the `Player` class.)

So then, I have a method where I want to query all `Character` that a `Player` has. So I have the following query set up...

```
        session.QueryOver<Player>()
            .Fetch(context => context.Characters).Eager
            .Take(1)
            .Future<Player>();

        session.QueryOver<Character>()
            .Future<Character>()
            .Take(10);

        return session.QueryOver<Member>()
            .Where(model)
            .Fetch(context => context.Player).Eager
            .List()
            .Take(1)
            .SingleOrDefault()
            .Player;
```

My thought here is that, from what I understand about the way `Future<T>` works (which may be way off is that it will eager load `Player` (1:1), which will perform the query for the `IList<Character>` in the same database trip, with a limit of 10 results. It will only take 1 Player per trip, and 1 Member per trip, and up to 10 characters per trip.

However `nhProf` is telling me I am using an unbounded request. Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Am I just misunderstanding how these methods work? Or can anyone provide an example that is a bit more viable? I don't understand HQL so I can't use the `CreateCriteria` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three queries in your question will do the following:

Query 1 will take the first Player it can find in the database, without any where-condition.

Query 2 will take the first ten Characters it can find, again without any where-condition.

Query 3 will execute the three queries and take the first Member matching your where-condition, along with the associated Player, and return the Member's Player.

If you wanted to iterate through the Player's Characters NHibernate would hit the DB again, since no Characters had been loaded, yet.

Your example could be done in a single query without Futures like this:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Member, bool>> model = m => m.Id == 1;
Member mAlias = null;
Player pAlias = null;
Character cAlias = null;

Member member = session.QueryOver<Member>(() => mAlias)
    .JoinAlias(m => m.Player, () => pAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => pAlias.Characters, () => cAlias)
    .Where(model)
    .List().FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is an example that may show better what Futures can do. The goal of the queries is to get the Customer with id = 1 and all his Orders and the Orders' Details and Bookings.

[image: Class diagram]

Now, if we want to load the Orders with their Details and Bookings together the resulting query would get us a cartesian product: `count(Details) * count(Bookings)`

```
int id = 1;
// define Aliases to use in query and be able to reference joined entities
Customer cAlias = null;
Order oAlias = null;
OrderDetails odAlias = null;
Booking bAlias = null;

// get the Customer and his Orders
var customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>(() => cAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(o => o.Orders, () => oAlias)
    .Where(c => c.Id == id)
    .Future<Customer>();

// get the Orders and their Details
var orders = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => oAlias)
    .JoinAlias(o => o.Customer, () => cAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => oAlias.Details, () => odAlias)
    .Where(() => cAlias.Id == id)
    .Future<Order>();

// get the Orders and their Bookings
var orders2 = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => oAlias)
    .JoinAlias(o => o.Customer, () => cAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => oAlias.Bookings, () => bAlias)
    .Where(() => cAlias.Id == id)
    .Future<Order>();

var list = customers.ToList();
Customer customer = list.FirstOrDefault();

Order o1 = customer.Orders.FirstOrDefault();
// iterate through the Details 
// normally this would cause N+1 selects, here it doesn't, because we already loaded
foreach (OrderDetails od1 in o1.Details)
{
    decimal d = od1.Quantity;
}
```

All my mappings work with lazy loading and I did not specify eager loading in those queries. Still, when I run the code, I get exactly three SQL queries in one roundtrip without a cartesian product. That's the beauty of Futures.

Comment: This is really good, and really useful. I've had a very hard time finding much to explain how futures worked, every resource I kept locating assumed you just natively 'understood' what they were. Ayende's blog had a very good post, but it used a lot of HQL and the example was not verbose enough for someone of my inexperience to draw from completely.

Comment: Even with this code, I still am being told I am using an 'Unbound Result Set'. I don't understand why, though.

Comment: @Ciel What code exactly? The query without Futures or the example with three queries? Did you add .SetMaxResults() to the queries above? Sorry, I have not yet used NHProf, so I can't experiment with that.

Comment: SetMaxResults is not a method on QueryOver - and I get the warnings on both codes. With and without the futures.

Comment: @Ciel You can try to use `.Take()`. That will result in a SQL string with `TOP x`. It should not matter if you take more than there are actually available.

Comment: Even using `.Take()` I am not seeing a `TOP x` in all of my queries. It seems very strange. I am still not entirely sure how all of this works, and it is frustrating because much of the information out there assumes a lot of dba background. My original goal was to just stop the database from making a trip on every lazy loaded element, but it seems this is turning into something much more.

Comment: About your `Futures` example, I am wondering - are the alias variables really necessary?

Comment: @Ciel Regarding the .Take() I will test this later again and post back here. Regarding the Aliases, these are necessary when referring to them in joins, like in the the second and third query where the where-condition refers to the Customer.

Comment: @Ciel I tested the `.Take(x)` again. If I have `.Where(() => cAlias.Id == id).Take(2).Future<Order>();` I get a `SELECT TOP(2)` (with variables of course) in the resulting SQL.

Comment: Great example Florian. I'm having difficulty getting the best performance though if you consider that OrderDetails and Booking contain far fewer rows than Orders. In my case, I'm getting n(Order) results for the OrderDetails query, and if I try to use futures by querying OrderDetails and joining in reverse fashion to the Order table, NH doesn't recognise the results and causes a Select N+1 when iterating the OrderDetails rows. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe The example code I offered above has the purpose of preventing a cartesian product. If you have "far fewer" rows in the tables that would cause an ugly cartesian product, you might be better off if you just put everything into one query. Depending on how many OrderDetails and Bookings are connected to each Order you might end up with more or less than 3*n(Order) rows. Try putting the joins together and see how many rows the resulting SQL gives you.

Comment: Florian, I am really in your debt for the examples you have provided on various QueryOver questions. I couldn't figure out why Take(x) wasn't working, and with your comment above, I saw the problem was that I was using Take() after Future().